# Binding lost in R Shiny with Datatables

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I'm trying to make a Shiny application with some checkboxes in a Datatable.
The first time the table is populated all is good, but when the datatable is rendered a second time with more rows the bindings of the existing checkboxes are lost.

Here is a minimal repro:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

rows=c("toto","titi","tata")

runApp(list(
  ui =   fluidPage(
    actionButton("run", label = "Run"),
    verbatimTextOutput('bindings'),
    DT::dataTableOutput('tblFilters')
  ),
  server= function(input, output, session) {
    values <- reactiveValues()
    values$filternames_df = data.frame()

    # create a character vector of shiny inputs
    shinyInput = function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
      inputs = character(len)
      for (i in seq_len(len)) {
        inputs[i] = as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, ...))
      }
      inputs
    }
    # obtain the values of inputs
    shinyValue = function(id, len) {
      unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) {
        value = input[[paste0(id, i)]]
        if (is.null(value)) NA else value
      }))
    }

    observeEvent(
      eventExpr = input$run,
      handlerExpr = {
        rows <<- c(rows,"tonton")
        values$filternames_df = data.frame(
          selected = shinyInput(checkboxInput, length(rows), 's_', value = TRUE),
          rows,
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      }
    )

    output$tblFilters <- DT::renderDataTable(
      values$filternames_df
      , escape = FALSE
      , options = list(preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                       drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
      )
    )
    output$bindings = renderPrint({
      data.frame(s = shinyValue('s_', nrow(values$filternames_df)))
    })
  }
))
```

The first time 'Run' is pressed, the bindings are ok. When we press 'Run' a second time, a 4th row is added to the datatable but the bindings of rows 1 to 3 do not work anymore, the 4th row is ok.
When we inspect the page, the rows 1 to 3 do not have the `class="shiny-bound-input"`:
we have

```
<input id="s_1" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
```

instead of

```
<input id="s_4" type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="shiny-bound-input">
```

Thanks!
Pat